How to validate that byte is greater or equal than specific value using FluentValidation?
I'm using the package FastEndpoints ( which ships FluentValidation ). Given a class defining the request object
using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

namespace MyProj;

public sealed class Request
{
    [JsonPropertyName("aProp")]
    public byte AProp { get; set; }
}

I also added a validator for this request
using FastEndpoints;
using FluentValidation;

namespace MyProj;

public sealed class RequestValidator : Validator<Request>
{
    public RequestValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.AProp)
            .GreaterThanOrEqualTo(2);
    }
}

Unfortunately I'm getting the error

Cannot resolve method 'GreaterThanOrEqualTo(int)', candidates are:   FluentValidation.IRuleBuilderOptions<MyProj.Request,byte> GreaterThanOrEqualTo<Request,byte>(this FluentValidation.IRuleBuilder<MyProj.Request,byte>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<MyProj.Request,byte>>) (in class DefaultValidatorExtensions)   FluentValidation.IRuleBuilderOptions<MyProj.Request,byte> GreaterThanOrEqualTo<Request,byte>(this FluentValidation.IRuleBuilder<MyProj.Request,byte>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<MyProj.Request,System.Nullable>>) (in class DefaultValidatorExtensions)

I also tried to add a generic like so .GreaterThanOrEqualTo<byte>(2); but then I get this error

Incorrect number of type parameters. Candidates are:   FluentValidation.IRuleBuilderOptions<T,System.Nullable> GreaterThanOrEqualTo<T,TProperty>(this FluentValidation.IRuleBuilder<T,System.Nullable>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T,System.Nullable>>) (in class DefaultValidatorExtensions)   FluentValidation.IRuleBuilderOptions<T,System.Nullable> GreaterThanOrEqualTo<T,TProperty>(this FluentValidation.IRuleBuilder<T,System.Nullable>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T,TProperty>>) (in class DefaultValidatorExtensions)   FluentValidation.IRuleBuilderOptions<T,System.Nullable> GreaterThanOrEqualTo<T,TProperty>(this FluentValidation.IRuleBuilder<T,System.Nullable>, TProperty) (in class DefaultValidatorExtensions)   FluentValidation.IRuleBuilderOptions<T,TProperty> GreaterThanOrEqualTo<T,TProperty>(this FluentValidation.IRuleBuilder<T,TProperty>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T,System.Nullable>>) (in class DefaultValidatorExtensions)   FluentValidation.IRuleBuilderOptions<T,TProperty> GreaterThanOrEqualTo<T,TProperty>(this FluentValidation.IRuleBuilder<T,TProperty>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T,TProperty>>) (in class DefaultValidatorExtensions)   FluentValidation.IRuleBuilderOptions<T,TProperty> GreaterThanOrEqualTo<T,TProperty>(this FluentValidation.IRuleBuilder<T,TProperty>, TProperty) (in class DefaultValidatorExtensions)

Unfortunately I don't know what's wrong. My property should not be nullable and at least be 2. How can I achieve that?

Have you tried RuleFor(x => x.AProp).GreaterThanOrEqualTo((byte)2); ?

the answer provided by @Fildor is correct. you have to cast the int value 2 to byte.

=> See also https://dotnetfiddle.net/PiCsaC
